# Compare last two created files with batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to compare the two last files created on a directory. The newest file **must be bigger than** the previous created file, if true just store to a variable.

If possible, I would like to get the **size** and **creation date** of both compared files.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Which language are you using? What have you tried and what's the problem?

Comment: I am using batch, I've tried to use FOR and FORFILES, but it is a bit difficult to me.

Answer (score 0):

A solution :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /a count=1

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /o-d /b') do (
 if !Count!==3 goto:next
 set "File!Count!=%%a"
 set "Size!Count!=%%~za"
 set /a Count+=1
)

:next
echo !File1! =^> !Size1!
echo !File2! =^> !Size2!

If !Size1! GTR !Size2! (
   echo OK
 ) else (
   echo KO
)
```